# Virtual << operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a slight problem where my << operator is not being called correctly.

This is what I have:

```
class SomeInterface
{
   friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, const SomeInterface& data);

   protected:
      virtual void print(ostream& str) const = 0;
};

inline std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, SomeInterface const& b)
{
  b.print(o);
  return o;
}
}
```

Calling code looks something like:

```
SomeInterface* one  = new someConcrete ();
cout << one;
```

The << overloaded function I was hoping would get called on the interface is not, let alone dispatching through to the derived class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
cout << *one;
```

Your code is asking to print the *pointer*, while your `operator<<` takes a `const SomeInterface&` reference.

Comment: Thanks...I should have guessed after it was printing address like garbage.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, void*);`, because the type of `one` is a pointer.

Try:

```
cout << *one;
```

This will call the overload that takes a (reference to) the actual object, not the pointer itself